# how to remove repeated values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contain three column like product Name,Sales rate and tax amount. i need the output if product name is repeating the very second row on wards product name should be empty and also sales rate and tax amount should be there in each and every row. that means the first product name should be there again its repeats set as empty

My table look like this

```
Product Name    SalesRate   TaxAmount
Apple            100         10
Lemon             50         5
Apple            120         12.5
```

I need the Output Like this

```
Product Name    SalesRate   TaxAmount
Apple            100         10
Lemon             50         5
                 120         12.5
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the source data layout and the desired output?

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your new sample data. Does it work for you? I'm missing a column you want to order by since it is none of the three shown columns.

Comment: Thats great work. i got the output using your solution . thank you Tim

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Product Name], SalesRate, TaxAmount,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY [Product Name]
                                   ORDER BY [Product Name], SalesRate, TaxAmount)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT [Product Name] = CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN '' ELSE [Product Name] END,
       SalesRate, 
       TaxAmount
FROM CTE
```

Instead of `ORDER BY [Product Name], SalesRate, TaxAmount` use an appropriate order.

Here is a  demo with your new sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bf55/4/0